# Upgrade IOS5 and XCODE 4 No provisioned iOS device is connected.

Tags: xcode, provisioning

I've upgrade IOS5 just today. I'm able to install provision files on my device. But I can't run the device on Xcode. it's says no provisioned devices are connected. It worked in the previous version of Xcode 4.0.2 without installing IOS5.

I pressed "development" button from manager. Itunes and Xcode upgrade confuses me a lot. My device won't shut off the connection after complete install. I unplugged the device. I pressed reset and power button for recovery. I plugged back it back again. I reinstall xcode over and over again from CD. I can't get xcode device work. I can't get Xcode 5 or download Xcode 4 on apple website. It doesn't work. I've download a new provision file on apple site.

I pressed run "no provisioned devices are connected."

Can any Xcode professional help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with iOS 5 and XCode 4, you need to get the latest version of XCode from http://developer.apple.com/ios.

If you can't retrieve it from there, you probably need to set up a (free!) Apple Developer account.

Once you download XCode 4.2, you can go to the Organizer (in XCode) and you'll see your device and click the "Use for Development" button and you should be all set.